# If you don't trust global variables, when you are inside of a method, how do you tell what class we are currently in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

This is a question about the general principle of introspection. When you are inside of a method, how can we make it possible to tell what class we are currently in?

We want something like as follows:

```
class FigNewton:
    def baz(self):
        current_class = MAGIC()
```

What would `MAGIC` be? The following is unacceptable, as we are working in an environment where call-time globals are not trusted. Globals at definition-time are trusted, but not globals at time-of-method-call.

```
class FigNewton:
    def baz(self):
        current_class = FigNewton
```

Why are globals not trusted at time-of-call? Because of shenanigans  like the following:

```
class FigNewton:
    def baz(self):
        current_class = FigNewton
        print("banana")
        print("current_class ==", current_class.__name__)

import itertools
import string
print = lambda *args, print=print:\
    print(
        sum(
            map(
                    lambda stryng:\
                        int(''.join(
                            itertools.takewhile(
                                lambda ch: ch in string.ascii_lowercase
                            ,
                                stryng
                            )
                       ), base=36)
                ,
                    map(str, args)
                )
            , )
        )

print("apple")

obj = FigNewton()
FigNewton = "apple"
obj.baz()
```

The output is:

```
17995730
683010982
27999997387
```

Instead of the expected:

```
apple
banana
current_class == FigNewton
```

Below is more code demonstrating the problem:

```
class K0:
    print=print
    type=type
    def foo(self, *args):
        self.print(40 * "--")
        self.print('args == ', args)
        self.print("K0 version of foo is executing.")
        self.print("Are all references to class K0 lost?")
        self.print("Well, global label `K0` is ", self.type(K0).__qualname__, K0)
        # K0.__getattribute__(self, "whatever") ## ERROR!!!
        tsqn = self.type(self).__qualname__
        self.print(
            "type(self) is ", tsqn,
            ". Is that K0? ", ("yes" if tsqn == "K0" else "no"),
            sep=""
        )
        self.print(40 * "--")

##########################################################
def test(seed_class):
    Ks = [seed_class]
    for idx in (1, 2, 3):
        K = type("K{}".format(idx), (Ks[-1],), dict())
        Ks.append(K)

    class K4(Ks[-1]):
        def foo(self):
            print("K10 version of foo is executing")
            print("type(self) is ", type(self))

    # Begin messing up global namespace
    global K0
    K0 = 0
    # End messing up global namespace
    Ks.pop(0)
    for K in Ks:
        obj = K()
        obj.foo(1, 2, 3)
    return None
##########################################################
test(K0)
```

The output is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
args ==  (1, 2, 3)
K0 version of foo is executing.
Are all references to class K0 lost?
Well, global label `K0` is  int 0
type(self) is K1. Is that K0? no
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
args ==  (1, 2, 3)
K0 version of foo is executing.
Are all references to class K0 lost?
Well, global label `K0` is  int 0
type(self) is K2. Is that K0? no
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
args ==  (1, 2, 3)
K0 version of foo is executing.
Are all references to class K0 lost?
Well, global label `K0` is  int 0
type(self) is K3. Is that K0? no
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

In the CPython reference interpreter, you can get the class a method was defined in by simply referencing `__class__`:

```
class FigNewton:
    def baz(self):
        current_class = __class__  # Assigns FigNewton, even if instance of subclass is used to invoke method
```

To my knowledge, this is an implementation detail of CPython (it's used to support no-arg `super()` calls, and I don't think it's mentioned anywhere other than in passing in the changelog and What's New documentation), so don't rely on it on other interpreters.

If you want the runtime type (so it reports the subclass type even when called in a method defined in the parent), use `type(self)` (or equivalently, `self.__class__`):

```
class FigNewton:
    def baz(self):
        current_class = type(self)  # Assigns FigNewton or a subclass thereof if instance of subclass is used to invoke method
```

Comment: I want the parent class (or possibly parent-parent-parent class), not type(self). I want the class which the method is defined inside of, not the run-time type.

Comment: `__class__` is also in the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/#specification) for 0-arg `super`, and in the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object). That said, I would consider its implementation-detail-ness somewhat fuzzy. It's not as clearly mandatory as having ints, but not as clearly optional as having the small int cache.

Comment: @martineau: If you're getting `__class__` and `self.__class__` mixed up, well, `__class__` is its own weird thing, and it behaves as this answer describes. If you're just proposing `self.__class__` as an alternative to `type(self)`, the answer already mentions that.

Comment: I meant the latter — and obvious missed that in your answer. Apologies.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon: Yeah, then `__class__` (the raw name, not the attribute of `self`) has you covered.

Answer (score -1):

The following is one kludgy solution, but it works:

```
class FigNewton:
    def baz(self):
        current_class = type(self).FigNewton
FigNewton.FigNewton = FigNewton
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you're worried about someone reassigning `FigNewton`, it's not clear why you wouldn't also be worried about someone reassigning `FigNewton.FigNewton`.

Comment: (In fact, this approach introduces the possibility of having `FigNewton.FigNewton` shadowed by subclass definitions of `FigNewton`. This may be more likely than getting a global stomped, since people have a tendency to think literally everything should be okay to override in a subclass.)

Comment: @user2357112 I think it's more likely, relatively speaking, that someone would accidentally write `K0 = something` than they would accidentally write `K0.K0 = something` or accidentally override `K0` in a subclass of `K0`

Comment: Oh. I see now that you're an alt of [*that* guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6676101/toothpick-anemone). Look, all these attempted technical solutions you keep asking about require you to change how you write all your code, in the hopes that doing so might allow you to write buggy code without fixing it. It's a bad approach.

Comment: If you're having chronic problems with stomping over your variables, you need better tools for detecting the problem, rather than trying to make clobbering your variables okay. If you're writing scripts, use linters and other static checkers. If you're in interactive mode, maybe set a `sys.interactivehook` that monitors your globals and gives you a warning and an undo button if you screw up.

Comment: @user2357112 You say that instead of avoiding global variables, I should simply use some tool to help ensure that I never shadow a global name. It is much easier to shadow globals than you think. For example, `func = lambda x: print(kwargs)` In that example, `kwargs` is global. I want the lambda function to print the `kwargs` that exists when the  function is defined not when the function is called. When the lambda function is called, `kwargs` may be completely different. `kwargs` is an extremely common label used in python programming. It gets "stomped" as you put it, all of the time.

Comment: I've never seen anybody use the name `kwargs` as a global. If you're doing that, that's really weird.

Comment: Are you under the impression that calling that `func` from inside `def func2(**kwargs): func(3)` would print the `kwargs` of the `func2` call or something? It doesn't matter what locals are in scope when `func` gets called. `func` will use the global `kwargs` from the global namespace where `func` was defined. It doesn't matter how many zillions of functions use `kwargs` as an argument name; it won't affect your (weird) global.